# Ayuda con el update en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo en php y mysql un codigo para editar un ticket pero al darle editar con los nuevos valores me dice el mensaje como si hubiera insertado pero no no meinserta en la base de datos

el codigo del ajax de editar

```
<?php
include('is_logged.php');
if (empty($_POST['mod_incidencia'])) {
       $errors[] = "incidencia vacío";
    }else if (empty($_POST['mod_detalle'])) {
       $errors[] = "detalle vacío";
    }else if (empty($_POST['mod_tema'])) {
       $errors[] = "tema vacío";
    }  else if (


    !empty($_POST['mod_tema']) &&
    !empty($_POST['mod_detalle']) &&
        !empty($_POST['mod_incidencia'])
    ){

    require_once ("../config/db.php");
    require_once ("../config/conexion.php");
    $incidencia=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["mod_incidencia"],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $tema=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["mod_tema"],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $detalle=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["mod_detalle"],ENT_QUOTES)));


    $Nticket=intval($_POST['mod_Nticket']);
    $sql="UPDATE ticket SET incidencia='".$incidencia."',  tema='".$tema."',
    detalle='".$detalle."' WHERE Nticket='".$Nticket."'";
    $query_update = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if ($query_update){
            $messages[] = "Ticket ha sido actualizado satisfactoriamente.";

           //me aparece este mensaje cuando ingreso pero no se actualiza en la BD\

                   } else{
            $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
        }
    } else {
        $errors []= "Error desconocido.";
    }

    if (isset($errors)){

        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>Error!</strong> 
                <?php
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                            echo $error;
                        }
                    ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        if (isset($messages)){

            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($messages as $message) {
                                echo $message;
                            }
                        ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
?>
```

Comment: Posiblemente `"' WHERE Nticket='".$Nticket."'"` no este encontrando nada de manera que el update es valido y retorna `true`. Revisa que en tu BD este el dato que corresponde con NTicket.

Comment: el Nticket es "id" de mi aplicacion

Comment: ¿En tu BD tienes una columna que se llama `Nticket` y dentro de los datos de la columna el valor es `id`? No se si me entendiste mal. El valor de la columna `Nticket` debe existir. Por ejemplo que sea un `10`. Entonces el valor que almacenas en `.$Ticket` también debe ser 10 o alguno que este registrado en la columna en tu BD. Si no existe coincidencia `$query_update` te retorna true porque aun así la sentencia se ejecutó correctamente.

Comment: si pero si pongo el valor de Nticket me dice que esta vacio

Comment: Haz un poco de debugueo. Revisa que `$Nticket=intval($_POST[mod_Nticket]);` si está recibiendo los datos.

Comment: Nticket lo tienes como char? o varchar? ya que en caso de que lo tuvieras como integer o algun tipo de numero, el problema podría ser las comillas simples que pones en el where

Comment: _me dice el mensaje como si hubiera insertado pero no no me inserta en la base de datos_  Al leer la pregunta pareciera que quieres insertar algo, ¿no estarás confundiendo actualizar con insertar? ¿Quieres _actualizar_ (`UPDATE`)  o _insertar_ (`INSERT`)? ¿Qué quieres actualizar o insertar?  También revisa las llaves de apertura y cierre de tu código, por ejemplo aquí: `} else{
            $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
        }
    } else {
        $errors []= "Error desconocido.";`  o hay algo mal o el código está desordenado.

Comment: hay dio mio aver cuadno digo que no me inserta en la base de datos quiero decir que no actualiza la BD por algo esta en el titulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba imprimiendo antes de tu petición la variable `$Nticket` para que verifiques que evidentemente está trayendo la información adecuada, de no ser así debes revisar en tu `js` el momento en el cual capturas y envías esas variables ya que el problema podría provenir de allí.

**Como consejo para que `debuggees` correctamente:** imprime la `variable` en cada uno de los pasos que usas para llegar al `update`, es decir saca `console.log()` en tu `js` y por un último un `echo` en tu `php` para que puedas verificar que desde el `front` hasta el `back` la `variable` llega correctamente, así podrás mirar en que momento se rompe tu código.

Espero te sirva, saludos !

Comment: crackkkkkkkkkkk